# SQL - Apply where conditions to multiple rows

Tags: sql

The question title might be a bit unclear, so I explain the situation:

I have a table languages

```
candidateprofile_id, language
=================================
1                      de
1                      fr
1                      en
2                      de
```

Which lists the languages a candidate is able to speak in seperate records.

The second table is language_proficiencies

```
candidateprofile_id, proficiency_code
====================================
1                      C2
1                      B1
1                      C1
2                      C2
```

Which lists the skill level candidates have for each language.

Now I want to select the IDs of all candidates, that speak a set of given languages with a certain proficiency.

For example, all candidates who speak german/de at C2 level, french/fr at B1 level and english/en at C1 level.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need a language column in the second table. Otherwise I don't see how to tell which proficiency code goes with with language for a given candidate.

Comment: The first proficiency row belongs to the first language row and so on. I agree that working with a single table would be easier, but I wanted to check for a sql solution before changing the db structure and the application.

Comment: Rows in tables are unordered. First has no meaning, in a SQL table, without reference to a value for the row used to produce the order.